# cygwin gcc exits with 1 but no error message

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I try to compile sloccount in cygwin but i have a strange problem with cygwin/gcc:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -c c_count.c
$ echo $?
1
$ ls c_count*
c_count.c
```

gcc does not show any error message but exits with error code 1 and did not compile anything.

[this link](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2002-04/msg00196.html) proposes to remove a second `cygwin1.dll`. I checked that with `cygcheck -s`, but there was only one .dll.

Any Suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have same problem except:                                                                         $ echo $?
127